# MYSQL inserting specific datas from columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Pupils and a table named Bus.

Bus contains an ID,Destination (where it goes to) and Time (when it leaves).

Pupils contains Name,Location(Where it lives) and BusID (Which bus it needs to take).

I want to fill the 'BusID' column with the correct 'ID' from the 'Bus' table (depending on the pupil's location and time selected).

**For example**, the pupil lives in Tel Aviv and wants a bus at 10:00.

I need to fill his 'BusID' column **AND ROW** ( there are many pupils) with the same 'ID' in the bus table where Destination equals Tel Aviv and Time equals 10:00.

Is it in anyway possible? I was thinking about using Insert into/Insert into select but it doesn't really fits my needs.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and the expected result? From your explanation there are buses that drive _to_ a certain location at a certain time and pupils that want to travel _from_ a certain location.

Comment: @PerlDog Yes I can.
Buses that drive to a certain location at a certain time and pupils that want to travel TO a certain location IN a certain time.


I can extract the specific data I want with the Select command
`SELECT ID
FROM Bus
WHERE Destination='Tel Aviv'  AND Time='10:00:00';`


That will provide me the ID of the bus the pupil needs to take to get to his home at the time he needs. (He lives in Tel Aviv and he wants to take the bus at 10:00:00).
Now I need the help to figure out how do I insert this data (the correct BusID) to this pupil.

Comment: Ahh, so then your pupils are somewhere else and want to go back home to Tel Aviv. Doesn't `update pupils set busid=(SELECT ID FROM bus WHERE Destination='Tel Aviv' AND Time='10:00:00') where location='Tel Aviv'` work?

Comment: Nice to hear. I'll put that in a real answer then.

Answer (score 0):

As I meanwhile understood: the pupils are somewhere else (presumably not in T.A.) and want to find the bus that brings them back to T.A. at 10:00 hrs.

This can then be achieved with

```
-- The id of the bus that travels at 10:00 to T.A.:
select id from bus where destination='Tel Aviv' and time='10:00:00';

-- Update the pupil's record with the bus-id:
update pupils set busid=... where location='Tel Aviv';

-- Together (and that's the answer):
update pupils set busid=(select id 
                           from bus 
                          where destination='Tel Aviv' 
                            and time='10:00:00')
              where location='Tel Aviv';
```

Note that this assumes there is exactly one result row in the first query, i.e. exactly one 10 o'clock bus to T.A.